# How to add user input together

Tags: c#

My program has to add the previous number entered to the next one. This is what I have so far, and I got stuck. It adds up the number that I have entered, but I don't understand how I have to validate one number from previous.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int QUIT = -1;
    string inputStr;
    int inputInt = 0;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Type a number (type -1 to quit): ");
        inputStr = Console.ReadLine();
        bool inputBool = int.TryParse(inputStr, out inputInt);

        if (inputBool == true)
            inputInt += inputInt;

        Console.WriteLine("Sum of the past three numbers is: {0}", inputInt);
    } while (inputInt != QUIT);
}
```

Since there may be an indefinite number of entries, I don't know how to properly use an array.

Comment: Use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do; if you have "an indefinite number of entries" are you trying to sum all of them? The last three? Every group of three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to find sum of numbers take another variable.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int QUIT = -1;
    string inputStr;
    int inputInt = 0,tempint=0;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Type a number (type -1 to quit): ");
        inputStr = Console.ReadLine();
        bool inputBool = int.TryParse(inputStr, out tempint);

        if (inputBool == true)
        {
            inputInt += tempint;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sum of the past three numbers is: {0}", inputInt);

    } while (tempint!= QUIT);


}
```

Comment: That text `"Sum of the past three numbers is:"` bugs me though. If you don't enter exactly three numbers, it's not, is it? Which is not due to a problem with this answer; it's the text in the original question which seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the simplest solution, you can just keep track of the past 3 numbers and sum them up when you print

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int QUIT = -1;
    string inputStr;
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    int i3 = 0;
    int inputInt = 0;
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Type a number (type -1 to quit): ");
        inputStr = Console.ReadLine();
        bool inputBool = int.TryParse(inputStr, out inputInt);

        if (inputBool == true)
        {
            i3 = i2;
            i2 = i1;
            i1 = inputInt;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sum of the past three numbers is: {0}", i1+i2+i3);

    } while (inputInt != QUIT);


}
```

Comment: Using a list<T> would be a better practise.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses LINQ and Queues to do what you want.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   const int QUIT = -1;
   string inputStr;
   int inputInt = 0;

   Queue myQ = new Queue();

   do
   {
      Console.Write("Type a number (type -1 to quit): ");
      inputStr = Console.ReadLine();
      bool inputBool = int.TryParse(inputStr, out inputInt);

      if (inputBool == true)
      {
         if (myQ.Count() == 3)
         {
            myQ.Dequeue();
            myQ.Enqueue(inputInt);
         }
         else
         {
            myQ.Enqueue(inputInt);
         } 
      }

      if (myQ.Count() == 3)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Sum of the past three numbers is: {0}", myQ.Sum());
      }

   } while (inputInt != QUIT);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list to store all of the numbers as they come in. Then at the end count how many items are in the list, and `Sum()` the entire list

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int QUIT = -1;
    string inputStr;
    List<int> allNumbers = new List<int>();
    do
    {
        Console.Write("Type a number (type -1 to quit): ");
        inputStr = Console.ReadLine();
        bool inputBool = int.TryParse(inputStr, out inputInt);

        if (inputBool == true)
            allNumbers.Add(inputInt); // Add a new element to the list
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of the past " + allNumbers.Count + " numbers is: {0}", allNumbers.Sum());
    } while (inputInt != QUIT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a local variable to hold the output from `int.TryParse`. Also you do not need a do while loop, you can exit immediately when the input is *-1*. With these changes, keeping up with the last 3 numbers becomes much easier:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const int QUIT = -1;
    int[] last3 = new int[3];
    // infinite loop, exit is done when input is -1
    for(;;) {
        Console.Write("Type a number (type -1 to quit): ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        int tmp; // holds the int value of the input
        if (int.TryParse(input, out tmp))
        {
            if (tmp == QUIT)
                break; // input is -1

            // input was an int, so lets move the last two towards
            // the front of the array, last3[0] contained the oldest value
            // which is gone now
            last3[0] = last3[1];
            last3[1] = last3[2];

            // now overwrite the last item in the array with the newest value 
            last3[2] = tmp;
        }

        // add up the values, note if input was not a valid int, this will sum
        // the last 3 valid values because the above if statement will only execute
        // and change the values in the array if the user input was a number
        var sum = last3[0] + last3[1] + last3[2];

        Console.WriteLine("Sum of the past three numbers is: {0}", sum);
    }
}
```